# J2ME PIM get contacts number alone

Tags: java, java-me, jsr, pim

Is there a way I can read a contacts number using the PIM API. I'm using the code below and it's just returning the name. I want the code to return the number only from a contact.

```
pim = PIM.getInstance();
    ContactsList.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
    try {
        String[] pimListNames = pim.listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);
        for (int i = 0; i < pimListNames.length; ++i) {
            ContactList cl = (ContactList) pim.openPIMList(
                    PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY, pimListNames[i]);
            Enumeration items = cl.items();
            while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
                Contact c = (Contact) items.nextElement();
                ContactsList.addItem(c.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0));
            }
        }
    } catch (PIMException ex) {
        WittyClassObject.showAlert("error", ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use

```
c.getString(Contact.TEL, 0) // instead of c.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0) ?
```